# copy text to client clipboard using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the below code. it's working fine

```
    $.each(data, function (index, d) {
        var clippy_swf = "swf/clippy.swf";
        $('#change_this').html('').clippy({ 'text': d.address_1, clippy_path: clippy_swf });
    });
```

but i'm trying to like this, it's not working here.

```
    $.each(data, function (index, d) {
        if (index != 0) {
            multiaddr += "<div><span >" + d.address_1 + "</span><span id='change_this_" + index + "'></span></div>";
            var clippy_swf = "swf/clippy.swf";
            $("#change_this_" + index + "").html('').clippy({ 'text': d.address_1, clippy_path: clippy_swf });
        }
    });
```

Comment: How to bind clippy event on dynamically created span??

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $('.someclass').append(multiaddr);
    $(document).find("#change_this_" + index + ").html('').clippy({ 'text': d.address_1, clippy_path: clippy_swf });
```

Instead of:

```
$("#change_this_" + index + "").html('').clippy({ 'text': d.address_1, clippy_path: clippy_swf });
```

You have too many `"` after `index` and try to find your new div inside document but you need to add it before

Comment: perfect remind to accept the answer when you can to help other person with your same problem :) @RohitKhurana

Answer (score 0):

try clippy https://github.com/mojombo/clippy
its simple and easy.
works on all browsers expect it depends on flash so it wont work in mobile browsers

Its what github uses